# durood shareef upon the prophet (SAW) and Ibrahim

Tags: islamic-basis

When im reading durood shareef I say, "Allahuma salli alla Muhammed" but I hear other people saying "Allahuma salli alla Muhammedin" instead. Which way is correct?

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct, depending on context.

[image: Durood sharif written in Arabic]

In the Arabic, the phrase ends in what is known as "kasratain", or "tanween with kasra" (circled in the above image) which is pronounced as "-in" at the end of the word. However, like other final vowels in Arabic, it would only be pronounced in the middle of a sentence, not at the end.

So, for example, if you're stopping after saying "Allahumma salli 'alaa Muhammad(in)", you would not pronounce the "-in" at the end. However, if you were reciting "Allahumma salli alaa Muhammad-in wa 'alaa aalihi", you *would* pronounce it in the middle of the sentence as you continue on with the rest of the durood. The meaning is the same, what matters is where you stop reciting.

Comment: and the same applies to Ibrahim?

Comment: @rondizzle Same principle applies, yes. Only difference is that in the Durood e Ibrahim, the final vowel in Ibrahim is an "-a" instead of "-in". So, "Ibrahim(a)", with the (a) pronounced or not  depending on where you stop.

Comment: So, if I'm not stopping and I want to recite the whole Durood Shareef, I can't say Muhammad and Ibrahim without adding the "in" and "A" at the end.

Comment: @rondizzle That's correct.

Comment: @rondizzle yes if the name Ibraheem wasn't a grammatical singularity (mamnu' min as-Sarf  ممنوع من الصرف indeclinable) it would be "'ala Ibraheemin", but this isn't correct, the correct version is "Allahuma Salli 'Ala aali Ibraheema".